# YouTube C# API Upload Large Video

Tags: c#, youtube-api

I am trying to upload a 500 MB video to YouTube, using the C# API. On the last line, I receive an argument null exception. What is the URI, which is the second argument, supposed to be? Here is my code:

```
[WebMethod]
public string InsertVideoToYouTube(FileStream fs, string filename, string title, string description, string userName, string password)
{
    Video newVideo = new Video();
    newVideo.Title = title;
    newVideo.Tags.Add(new MediaCategory("Sports", YouTubeNameTable.CategorySchema));
    newVideo.Description = description;
    newVideo.YouTubeEntry.Private = false;
    newVideo.YouTubeEntry.MediaSource = new MediaFileSource(fs, Path.GetFileName(filename), "video/x-ms-wmv");

    var youTubeAuthenticator = new ClientLoginAuthenticator("KenticoVideo",
                    ServiceNames.YouTube, new GDataCredentials(userName, password));
youTubeAuthenticator.DeveloperKey = "xxx";
    ResumableUploader uploader = new ResumableUploader(256);

    uploader.Insert(youTubeAuthenticator, new Uri("http://www.mysite.com"), fs, "video/x-ms-wmv", ""); // start upload
}
```

Here is the stack trace:

```
System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: uriString
   at System.Uri..ctor(String uriString)
   at Google.GData.Client.ResumableUpload.ResumableUploader.InitiateUpload(Uri resumableUploadUri, Authenticator authentication, String contentType, String slug, Int64 contentLength, String httpMethod)
   at Google.GData.Client.ResumableUpload.ResumableUploader.InitiateUpload(Uri resumableUploadUri, Authenticator authentication, String contentType, String slug, Int64 contentLength)
   at Google.GData.Client.ResumableUpload.ResumableUploader.Insert(Authenticator authentication, Uri resumableUploadUri, Stream payload, String contentType, String slug, AsyncData data)
   at Google.GData.Client.ResumableUpload.ResumableUploader.Insert(Authenticator authentication, Uri resumableUploadUri, Stream payload, String contentType, String slug)
   at PreveaYTProxy.InsertVideoToYouTube(FileStream fs, String filename, String title, String description, String userName, String password) in c:\inetpub\wwwroot\Customers\imaginasium\PreveaYTProxy\App_Code\PreveaYTProxy.cs:line 57
   at _Default.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in c:\inetpub\wwwroot\Customers\imaginasium\PreveaYTProxy\Default.aspx.cs:line 20
   at System.Web.Util.CalliEventHandlerDelegateProxy.Callback(Object sender, EventArgs e)
   at System.Web.UI.Control.OnLoad(EventArgs e)
   at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
```

Am I using the correct code? I looked here, but I cannot find the code I need:

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/gdata-dotnet-client-library/AWoPGB9_NzE

Comment: Did you increase your size limit, as described on [this page?](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/71673?hl=en)  Have you read the section titled "I'm having problems uploading a long video"?

Comment: I just tried that, however, the error persists. I just added the stack trace. Perhaps it's an issue with the URI property?

Comment: http://idevhub.com/programmatically-uploading-videos-to-youtube/

Comment: Do you know where the trails in the sand YouTube library is located? The link gives me a 404.

Comment: You should try using fiddler and look at the response from the server. The exception you are getting is due to the response from the server missing the "Location" header. Looking at the response in fiddler should help you find out if this is because of how you are using the api or maybe there is an issue with this part of the api library.

Comment: Do you still need this? I can help because I did the exact thing.

Comment: I wish you were here 2 months ago! Can you post your code? Did you do it with Xamarin?